# How to run composer.patch on Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, patches, composer

I am trying to run this patch

```
PATCH_MDVA-4538_EE_2.1.4_v2.composer.patch
```

when I simply run the patch command it hangs. Is there a composer.patch command that I need to do?